# Textarea toolbar?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on a formatting toolbar for a textarea, much like the toolbar for writing questions on this very site (with the bold, italic, underline buttons). The only difference is that I need the buttons to make the text actually bold not just add a bold tag. What I need is similar to the Instructables.com rich comment editor, or the newgrounds.com comment editor, or  google docs. Does anyone have a clue how I can make some text in a textarea show up bold, italic, or underlined but keep the rest of it?

Comment: Just from looking at google doc's html: they use <div> and <span>. i.e. each block of continuous text with the same formatting is within a <span>

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of implementations of javascript WYSIWYG eitors. FCKEditor (now [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo)) was one of the first. [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php) was popular for a long time. I've recently used [TinyEditor](http://www.scriptiny.com/2010/02/javascript-wysiwyg-editor/).

There's also [nicedit](http://nicedit.com/), 10 editors listed and compared [here](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors), not to mention the answers previously provided here on SO to the question of [what's available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441521/lightest-wysiwyg-html-editor).

An they don't have to produce HTML - there are also editors producing [Wiki markup](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/WYSIWYG_editor)

Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

I found how to create own Rich Text Editor just like this :

```
(function ($) {
    if (typeof $.fn.rte === "undefined") {
        var defaults = {
            content_css_url: "rte.css",
            media_url: "images",
            dot_net_button_class: null,
            max_height: 350
        };
        $.fn.rte = function (options) {
            $.fn.rte.html = function (iframe) {
                return iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
            };
            var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function () {
                var textarea = $(this);
                var iframe;
                var myID = textarea.attr("id");
                var settings = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, textarea.data()) : opts;
                var sel = {
                    cmdBtnSelector: "." + settings.dot_net_button_class
                };


                function enableDesignMode() {
                    var content = textarea.val();
                    if ($.trim(content) == '') {
                        content = '<br />';
                    }
                    if (iframe) {
                        textarea.hide();
                        $(iframe).contents().find("body").html(content);
                        $(iframe).show();
                        $("#toolbar-" + myID).remove();
                        textarea.before(toolbar());
                        return true;
                    }
                    iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                    iframe.frameBorder = 0;
                    iframe.frameMargin = 0;
                    iframe.framePadding = 0;
                    iframe.height = 200;
                    if (textarea.attr('class')) iframe.className = textarea.attr('class');
                    if (textarea.attr('id')) iframe.id = myID;
                    if (textarea.attr('name')) iframe.title = textarea.attr('name');
                    textarea.after(iframe);
                    var css = "";
                    if (settings.content_css_url) {
                        css = "<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + settings.content_css_url + "' />";
                    }
                    var doc = "<html><head>" + css + "</head><body class='frameBody'>" + content + "</body></html>";
                    tryEnableDesignMode(doc, function () {
                        $("#toolbar-" + myID).remove();
                        textarea.before(toolbar());
                        textarea.hide();
                    });
                }
                function tryEnableDesignMode(doc, callback) {
                    if (!iframe) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    try {
                        iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
                        iframe.contentWindow.document.write(doc);
                        iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                    if (document.contentEditable) {
                        iframe.contentWindow.document.designMode = "On";
                        callback();
                        return true;
                    } else if (document.designMode != null) {
                        try {
                            iframe.contentWindow.document.designMode = "on";
                            callback();
                            return true;
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log(error)
                        }
                    }
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        tryEnableDesignMode(doc, callback)
                    }, 250);
                    return false;
                }
                function disableDesignMode(submit) {
                    var content = $(iframe).contents().find("body").html();
                    if ($(iframe).is(":visible")) {
                        textarea.val(content);
                    }
                    if (submit !== true) {
                        textarea.show();
                        $(iframe).hide();
                    }
                }
                function toolbar() {
                    var tb = $("<div class='rte-toolbar' id='toolbar-" + myID + "'><div>\
              <p>\
                  <select>\
                      <option value=''>Block style</option>\
                      <option value='p'>Paragraph</option>\
                      <option value='h3'>Title</option>\
                  </select>\
              </p>\
              <p>\
                  <a href='#' class='bold'><img src='" + settings.media_url + "text_bold.png' alt='bold' title='Bold' /></a>\
                  <a href='#' class='italic'><img src='" + settings.media_url + "text_italic.png' alt='italic' title='Italicize' /></a>\
              </p>\
              <p>\
                  <a href='#' class='unorderedlist'><img src='" + settings.media_url + "text_list_bullets.png' alt='unordered list' title='Unordered List' /></a>\
                  <a href='#' class='link'><img src='" + settings.media_url + "link.png' alt='link' title='Hyperlink' /></a>\
                  <a href='#' class='image'><img src='" + settings.media_url + "image.png' alt='image' title='Image' /></a>\
                  <a href='#' class='disable'><img src='" + settings.media_url + "code.png' alt='close rte' title='View Code' /></a>\
              </p></div></div>");
                    $('select', tb).change(function () {
                        var index = this.selectedIndex;
                        if (index != 0) {
                            var selected = this.options[index].value;
                            formatText("formatblock", '<' + selected + '>');
                        }
                    });
                    $('.bold', tb).click(function () {
                        formatText('bold');
                        return false;
                    });
                    $('.italic', tb).click(function () {
                        formatText('italic');
                        return false;
                    });
                    $('.unorderedlist', tb).click(function () {
                        formatText('insertunorderedlist');
                        return false;
                    });
                    $('.link', tb).click(function () {
                        var p = prompt("URL:");
                        if (p) formatText('CreateLink', p);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $('.image', tb).click(function () {
                        var p = prompt("image URL:");
                        if (p) formatText('InsertImage', p);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $('.disable', tb).click(function () {
                        disableDesignMode();
                        var edm = $('<a href="#">Enable design mode</a>');
                        tb.empty().append(edm);
                        edm.click(function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            enableDesignMode();
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                    if (settings.dot_net_button_class != null) {
                        var cmdBtn = $(iframe).parents('form').find(sel.cmdBtnSelector);
                        cmdBtn.click(function () {
                            disableDesignMode(true);
                        });
                    } else {
                        $(iframe).parents('form').submit(function () {
                            disableDesignMode(true);
                        });
                    }
                    var iframeDoc = $(iframe.contentWindow.document);
                    var select = $('select', tb)[0];
                    iframeDoc.mouseup(function () {
                        setSelectedType(getSelectionElement(), select);
                        return true;
                    });
                    iframeDoc.keyup(function () {
                        setSelectedType(getSelectionElement(), select);
                        var body = $('body', iframeDoc);
                        if (body.scrollTop() > 0) {
                            var iframe_height = parseInt(iframe.style['height']);
                            if (isNaN(iframe_height)) {
                                iframe_height = 0;
                            }
                            var h = Math.min(opts.max_height, iframe_height + body.scrollTop()) + 'px';
                            iframe.style['height'] = h;
                        }
                        return true;
                    });
                    return tb;
                }
                function formatText(command, option) {
                    iframe.contentWindow.focus();
                    try {
                        iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand(command, false, option);
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e)
                    }
                    iframe.contentWindow.focus();
                }
                function setSelectedType(node, select) {
                    while (node.parentNode) {
                        var nName = node.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                        for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
                            if (nName == select.options[i].value) {
                                select.selectedIndex = i;
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        node = node.parentNode;
                    }
                    select.selectedIndex = 0;
                    return true;
                }
                function getSelectionElement() {
                    if (iframe.contentWindow.document.selection) {
                        selection = iframe.contentWindow.document.selection;
                        range = selection.createRange();
                        try {
                            node = range.parentElement();
                        } catch (e) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        try {
                            selection = iframe.contentWindow.getSelection();
                            range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
                        } catch (e) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        node = range.commonAncestorContainer;
                    }
                    return node;
                }
                enableDesignMode();
            });
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It would have been better if you included some explanations about the code

Answer (score 0):

The `contentEditable` DOM attribute is used make the document or a section of it editable. This doesn't work with a `<textarea>`; more often an `<iframe>` is created and the document inside of it used as an editor.

Mark Pilgrim has [an article explaining it](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable) on the blog of the Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group. It includes [an example page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand/) showing some of the features in use.