# PHP Session Help

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I have read up on how to use Sessions in PHP but I am struggling to understand and implement it.
After looking at some examples on Google, they all seem vague and too complex. What I am trying to implement is the following:

The user logs in, when the submit button is pressed, they are redirected to another page where the user's name will show up.
Could you help me with doing this by showing simple examples?

Comment: Have you got some code? What have you tried? It should be fairly simple this, so if you post some code we can probably tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: are you trying to implement session stored in a database or you just tagged your question this way to get more attention?

Comment: You don't need a session (and shouldn't use the session) to do what you want to do. The name is in the request parameters No need to store it in the session.

Comment: This is actually database related since  I will store the name in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the session on each page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Set a variable in the session array.

```
<?php $_SESSION['username'] = 'Roel Veldhuizen'; ?>
```

And echo a variable, on the same or other page

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>
```

Can't make it any simpler. You should do some checkings for security.

Comment: But how do I use it using a form? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

php.net provides a lot of documentation and examples. I've written a bit of example code below.

Script that handles the form input:

```
session_start();
$_session['name'] = $_POST['name'];
header('location: nextpage.php');
```

nextpage.php

```
session_start();
echo 'Your name is: '.$_SESSION['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

No clue what you are having trouble with, but seems like you have a form that submits to a PHP page, and want the username to display on that page, and be displayed on all pages afterwards.

Sample Form:

```
<form name="submitName" action="saveName.php" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="usersName" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

PHP to Process Form (`saveName.php`)

```
<?php
    session_start(); // Starts the session so you can save the name
    $name = $_POST['usersName']; // Get the name submitted
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name; // Save the name in a session
    echo strip_tags($name); // Output the user's name to the HTML page, after removing PHP and HTML tags from string
?>
```

On later pages, `$_SESSION['name']` contains the user's name.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['name'];
    }
    else {
        echo <<<USERFORM
<form name="submitName" action="saveName.php" method="POST">
    Please enter your name: <input type="text" name="usersName" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
USERFORM;
    }
?>
```

If you redefine your question, we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement a Login system using Session. in my earlier post i have explained on how to deal with it.

have a look at this post and check for my answer. [Login System Using PHP Session.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897650/open-source-rich-html-editor/6898038#6898038)